# TypeError: undefined is not a function in discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I keep having this error and it always keeps referring to 14:19 (the `[list]` part):

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Here's my meme command:

```js
const got = require('got');
const Discord  = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    name: "meme",
    description: "Shows a random meme.",
    async execute(message, args) {
        const subReddits = ["memes", "dankmemes", "comedyheaven", "historymemes", "Fauxcyrillic"];
        const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];

        const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed();
        got(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${random}/random/.json`)
        .then(response => {
            const [list] = JSON.parse(response.body);
            const [post] = list.data.children;

            const permalink = post.data.permalink;
            const memeUrl = `https://reddit.com${permalink}`;
            const memeImage = post.data.url;
            const memeTitle = post.data.title;
            const memeUpvotes = post.data.ups;
            const memeNumComments = post.data.num_comments;

            embed.setTitle(`${memeTitle}`);
            embed.setURL(`${memeUrl}`);
            embed.setColor(26763);
            embed.setImage(memeImage);
            embed.setFooter(` ${memeUpvotes}  ${memeNumComments}`);

            message.channel.send(embed);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    },
};
```

Comment: I have no experience with `got` but the `JSON.parse()` method seems to be causing the error. Do you not have to define a variable as the `got()` func? That is perhaps the reason there is an undefined error.

Comment: If the `JSON.parse(...)` is causing the error it means that the string is not correctly formatted. Have you tried to `console.log()` the `got(...)` output?

Comment: i made it a variable but its still giving me an error: const response = await got(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${random}/random/.json`). Here's the readme: https://www.npmjs.com/package/got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the returned value is not always an array, sometimes it's a single object. When it's not an array, you cant destructure `list` (`const [list] = ...`). You need to check if the `response.body` is an array. If it's an array, grab the first element, otherwise leave it as is. Check the update code below:

```js
const embed = new MessageEmbed();
const subReddits = [
  'memes',
  'dankmemes',
  'comedyheaven',
  'historymemes',
  'Fauxcyrillic',
];
const random = subReddits[Math.floor(Math.random() * subReddits.length)];

try {
  const response = await got(`https://www.reddit.com/r/${random}/random/.json`);
  const body = JSON.parse(response.body);
  const posts = Array.isArray(body) ? body[0] : body;
  const post = posts.data.children[0].data;

  const memeUrl = `https://reddit.com${post.permalink}`;
  const memeImage = post.url;
  const memeTitle = post.title;
  const memeUpvotes = post.ups;
  const memeNumComments = post.num_comments;

  embed.setTitle(`${memeTitle}`);
  embed.setURL(`${memeUrl}`);
  embed.setColor(26763);
  embed.setImage(memeImage);
  embed.setFooter(` ${memeUpvotes}  ${memeNumComments}`);

  message.channel.send(embed);
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}
```

I used `async/await` to get the response as you've already got an async `execute` method.

Comment: It seems to be working but from time to time it says that: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body. embed.title: Must be 256 or fewer in length. But I assume that that's just the post title length problem, right?

Comment: Yes, it seems you need to cut the title if it's too long. `memeTitle = post.title.slice(0, 256)` should work, but you could also use [lodash truncate](https://lodash.com/docs/#truncate) for example (especially if you want to set the max length without cutting words).